# I use change event but I when I put value to the select option on course the major does not append data..

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

> First I have to select a course after I select options from major will append on the second select

**the problem is**

- when i put value to the course option the major option will not append
- when I remove the value the major will append

Please help me I dont know where was ther error..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

     <?php 
  include'connection.php';
  $sql = "select * from course";
  $res=$conn->query($sql);
  while ($row=$res->fetch_array()) 
    {
       $course[]=$row['course_name'];
    }

?>
<?php

foreach ($course as $coursename) 
  {

  echo "var ".$coursename." = [ ";

  $sql = "Select *,course.course_name,course.course_name from major inner join course on course.course_id = major.course_id where course_name = '".$coursename."'";
  $res=$conn->query($sql);
  while($row=$res->fetch_array())
    { 
    ?>

    {display:"<?php echo $row['major_name'];?>", value:"<?php echo $row['major_id'];?>"},
    
    <?php
    }
echo '];';
  }

?>

// Function executes on change of first select option fiel

$("#course").change(function(){
var select = $("#course option:selected").val();
switch (select) 
  {
  <?php 
  $sql="select * from course";
  $res=$conn->query($sql);
  $count=$res->num_rows;
    while($row=$res->fetch_array()) 
      {  
          ?>
          case "<?php echo $row['course_name']; ?>":
          major(<?php echo $row['course_name']; ?>); 
          break;

          <?php

      }

  ?>
  default:
  $("#major").empty();
  $("#major").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
  break;
  }
});

// Function To List out Cities in Second Select tags
function major(arr)  
  {
  $("#major").empty(); //To reset cities
  $("#major").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
  $(arr).each(function(i) 
    { //to list cities
    $("#major").append("<option value=\"" + arr[i].value + "\">" + arr[i].display + "</option>")
    });
  }
  function course(arr) {
  $("#course").empty(); //To reset cities
  $("#course").append("<option>--Select--</option>");
  $(arr).each(function(i) { //to list cities
  $("#course").append("<option value=\"" + arr[i].value + "\">" + arr[i].display + "</option>")
  });
  }
});
</script>
```

```html
 <label for="form_phone">10.Course</label>
                  <select name="course_id" id="course" class="form-control" required="">
                  <option>--Select--</option> 
                   <?php
                    include"connection.php";
                    $res=$conn->query ("Select course_id,course_name from course");
                      $count=$res->num_rows;
                      if($count > 0)
                  {
                       while($row=$res->fetch_array())
                    {
                    ?>

                  <option value="<?php echo $row['course_name']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $row['course_name'];?>
                  </option>

                  <?php
                  }
                    }   
                  ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_phone">11.Major</label>
                                        <select name="major" id="major" class="form-control">
                                        
                                      <!-- dependent on course -->
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're saying 'append' do you mean the options for the majors aren't populating the drop down based on the criteria of the course selection?

Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes thats it . but it does not work if I put value on course option